# Angularjs : Bind ng-model data through code

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I have used `ng-repeat` for dynamic control generation. When generating dynamic input control i'm binding `ng-model` as shown below.

```
<div class="tabbable" tabs="">

    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" ng-init=" info.tab=1; myOne={}">
        <li ng-repeat="data in info" heading="{{data.title}}" ng-click="data.tab=data.DataID">
            <a href="#">{{data.Label}}</a>
        </li>

    </ul>

    <div ng-repeat="data in info">
        <h1>{{data.Label}}</h1>
        <hr />
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-5">
                <div ng-repeat="fld in data.Fields" >                    
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-4" align="right">
                            <div>{{fld.FieldLabel}} :</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-5">
                            <input type="text" ng-model="myOne[fld.FieldID]" id="{{fld.FieldID}}" ng-change="fill(fld.FieldName,myOne[fld.FieldID])" />                                
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-3" >
                            {{fld.Unit}}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

Scenario is, when I input data through input field i'm able to capture, manipulate and save data to database. Now while I'm fetching data from database i'm having values in another json field(`StoredValue`).
I would like to map data from `StoredValue` to `myOne[fld.FieldID]`, so that i can display all data in dynamically generated input field (during `read` operation). Can we do that through code behind or is there any way we do inline.

Comment: use ng-model="fld.fieldValue"

Comment: you would need to map `data.fields` to `myOne` in controller or service. Also note improper use of `ng-init`. Do initialization in controller, not in view

Comment: Any fiddle will be helpful